# Remove an object from a nested array with $pull and $[identifier] (mongoDB 3.6)

Tags: mongodb

MongoDB 3.6 allow to perform complex array manipulations against all matching elements in any array – no matter how deeply nested – [Update Nested Arrays with $[identifier]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/)

Consider the document below on `survey` collection:

```
{
    "_id": "5a7d86d8fac139e71b0b9f5b",
    "results": [
      {
        "items": [
          {
            "comments": [
              {
                "id" : "123456",
                "email": "user@email.com",
                "comment": "comment 1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I'm trying to remove a comment based on comment `id` using `$pull` and the new `$[<identifier>]`

I tried the `command` below based on [The update command](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/update/) :

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "survey",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {},
      u: {
        $pull: {
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments.$[comment]": { "comment.id": { $eq: "123456" } }
        }
      },
      arrayFilters: [{ "comment.id": { $eq: "123456" } }]
    }
  ]
})
```

But it didn't work because `$pull` expect an array value:
`Cannot apply $pull to a non-array value`

Any help ? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [`positional all` $[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/) variant.

Something like

```
db.runCommand({
  update: "survey",
  updates: [
    {
      q: {},
      u: {
        $pull: {
          "results.$[].items.$[].comments": { "id":  "123456" }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
})
```