# Update nested object in an array in mongoose using its id

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Below is my database. I want to update a object in perDayDetails array using its id in mongoose

```
"_id":{"$oid":"612f45863106a21bc0506a36"},
"fullname":"abc xyz",
"details":
[
  {
    "_id":{"$oid":"613106f8c5e7ec240c36e1fa"},
    "startDate":{"$date":"2021-09-10T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "endDate":{"$date":"2021-09-21T00:00:00.000Z"},
    "destination":"def",
    "perDayDetails":
    [
      {
        "_id":{"$oid":"6135eb384a5f7c3440b8b083"},
        "morningPlace":"hi",
        "morningFood":"hi",
        "nightPlace":"hi",
        "nightFood":"hi"
      },
      {
        "_id":{"$oid":"6135eb394a5f7c3440b8b084"},
        "morningPlace":"hello",
        "morningFood":"hello",
        "nightPlace":"hello",
        "nightFood":"hello"
      }
    ]
  }
],
"__v":0
```

Currently, I am replacing the entire array by updating it in the frontend. Is there any optimal solution for it like using its object id for updating or deleting that nested object...

Comment: I think you need to split it into multiple models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
collection.update(
    {
        
    },
    { "$set": { 
        "details.$[outer].perDayDetails.$[inner].morningPlace": morningPlace,
        "details.$[outer].perDayDetails.$[inner].morningFood": morningFood,
        "details.$[outer].perDayDetails.$[inner].nightPlace": nightPlace,
        "details.$[outer].perDayDetails.$[inner].nightFood": nightFood 
    } },
    { "arrayFilters": [
        { "outer._id": details_id },
        { "inner._id": preDayDetails_id}
    ] }
```

you could update each field of object in perDayDetails , and if you don't update field remove from `set`

Comment: Okay thanks! And what if I want to delete the object whose objectid is "6135eb394a5f7c3440b8b084"

Comment: use this for delete
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705828/remove-an-object-from-a-nested-array-with-pull-and-identifier-mongodb-3-6/48707161