# How can I $pull an array under array of object

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a DB like:

```
"userId": "sdsdad-dsdsds",
"userName": "user1",
"videos": [
 {
  "name": "video_541d",
  "likes": ["user1,", "user1"],
 },{
  "name": "video_3212",
  "likes": ["user1,", "user1", "user3"],
 },
],
```

I want to remove a specific user from likes array.

```
const result = await User.updateOne(
      { userName, 'videos.name': videoName, 'videos.likes': userId },
      { $pull: { 'videos.$.likes': userId } }
    );
```

Comment: What is the current outcome? What is your desired outcome?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove an object from a nested array with $pull and $\[identifier\] (mongoDB 3.6)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48705828/remove-an-object-from-a-nested-array-with-pull-and-identifier-mongodb-3-6)

Comment: @Markus I have mongoose error: Cannot create field "likes"..... I want to remove a specific user under likes array.

Comment: @ray does not work for my problem.

Comment: @AlphaAndrianarivo What does not work? Have you checked out the link I provided and the concept of using $[]? If so, can you provide your current attempt so we can take a closer look?

Comment: @ray thank you so much, it's workting ```$pull: {
    "videos.$[].likes": userID,
   },```

Comment: @ray The new problem is it pulls all the userID from all the likes array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bit of confusion of what you actually need so here are two options:

**Option 1**

This will match a `user` and pull the value from the `videos.likes` array of **only** the `videos` array element that matched your query:

```js
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName: userName , 'videos.name': videoName, 'videos.likes': userId },
    { 
        $pull: {
          "videos.$.likes": userId
        } 
    },
    {new: true}
);
```

See [HERE](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/KWro8PDlAOe) for a full working example.

**Option 2**

This will match a `user` and pull the value from the `videos.likes` array of **all** `videos.likes` arrays from the matching document:

```js
const result = await User.findOneAndUpdate(
    { userName: userName , 'videos.name': videoName, 'videos.likes': userId },
    { 
        $pull: {
          "videos.$[].likes": userId
        } 
    },
    {new: true}
);
```

See [HERE](https://www.mycompiler.io/view/6geiDq7uC4Y) for a full working example.

**Note**: in your sample documents you have a couple of occurrences of `user1,` which has a comma `,` after the `user1`. This may have been a typo and causing you issues.